# Can't get Copilot working after VS update

Tags: visual-studio-2022, github-copilot

I have more stations. This issue is on one only - for now:

- Copilot log:

  ```
  GitHub Copilot 1.116.0.0 (v1.116.0.0@5a26aa711)
  GitHub Copilot Agent v1.116.0
  [DEBUG] [agent] [2023-11-18T10:12:22.845Z] Agent service starting
  [DEBUG] [agent] [2023-11-18T10:12:23.641Z] Telemetry initialized
  Auth Status: NotSignedIn
  ```

plus:
[image]

- Click on "Add GitHub account". Of course, it is already added, but asks to reauthorize: [image]
- No problem. I click on it. I immediately get (no credentials asked unless I log out from github):
  [image]

Cute!

[image]

Even cuter!

Except... the warning does not disappear and the service does not log in.

If I restart VS, I am where I started...

I have logged out from GH, I have removed my account from VS, and added it again, same result.

Comment: @Rob Interestingly, it just went away after a while. I did not update anything. I noticed that the web page I made the screenshot of took much longer to load - then it worked instantly. Before it was just a bliss. You could try clearing the browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I work on Visual Studio)

It's worth reporting an issue to the Visual Studio team via the "report a problem" feature: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report If you do and post a link here I can follow up to make sure it gets triaged. Thanks!